# xsl:include not working from a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, xslt, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension that uses XSL transformations. I
have been using XSLTProcessor without problems until I needed to do an
xsl:include from the XSL stylesheet. When I import the XSL stylesheet
that uses an xsl:include, Firefox gives an error:

> Error: Component returned failure
>   code: 0x80600001
>   [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet] =
>    Source file:
>   chrome://myextension/content/functions.js
>   Line: 632

This only happens when running the code **from the Firefox extension**, if
I run it in "normal" html page the code works perfectly. I also tried
with xsl:import and got the same result. I also tried with absolute URIs like `chrome:\\myextension\content\xsl\test2.xsl` and get the same error.

Does anyone know what could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Here goes the code to reproduce it (all files are in the same folder):

File **functions.js**:

```
function testXSL(){
        var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
        var xsl = document.implementation.createDocument("", "test", null);
        xsl.addEventListener("load", onXSLLoaded, false);

        xsl.load("test1.xsl");
        function onXSLLoaded() {
           processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        }
}
```

File **test1.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<xsl:include href="test2.xsl" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

File **test2.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <xsl:template match="/">
                <h1>Included!!</h1>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a Firefox regression bug. I found [this one on Mozilla bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=422502).
I'm afraid nobody can help you here unless the bug is patched, and that doesn't smell good...open 2 years ago, no update since 6 months.

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked bugzilla before posting. Let's hope the bug get some attention.